# How can i change mulitple line within a tag into one line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, line

These are 2 lines within `P` tag:

```
<p>2 years of teaching experience on English second paper from class six to ten in Biddapath and Onnesha Coaching Centre, Mirpur 1.
Moreover, I have one year of experience on Private teaching in my home district. I had 3 batches of about 40 students, class 9,10 & 11 on English Second Paper.</p>
```

And here is a string with 3 lines within `p` tag:

```
    <p>2 years of teaching experience on English second paper from class six to ten in Biddapath and Onnesha Coaching Centre, Mirpur 1.
Moreover, 
I have one year of experience on Private teaching in my home district. I had 3 batches of about 40 students, class 9,10 & 11 on English Second Paper.</p>
```

There are strings with 4 lines within `p` tag.
I want to change all lines within `p` into one single lines.
Is that possible with Notepad++ regex?

Comment: there is no nested <p> tag, how can i do it please give me the code, thanks

Comment: thanks, it's works! I have another data, if there is ""(double quotation at start and end) not <p></p>, then what code will be?

Comment: please update your question with what you tried before, then I will post an answer.

Comment: I have tried this ("|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!")[^\r\n])*\K\R+, but it create all lines into one line

Comment: With `""`, there is a problem since the leading=trailing delimiter. Is there any specific requirement/specs for it? Like what can be possible context for these double quotes?

Comment: I have 300 rows of wrap text in excel, when I copy and paste it into notepad++, I has taken double quotes at start and end, I want to remove quotes and make every wrap text into one line.

Comment: So, those *leading* `""` are either at the start of a line, or after a tab character? And it looks like `"""aha"""<TAB>"got it"<TAB>"""now""."`?

Comment: Try [`((?:^|\t)""|\G(?!\A))[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?!")[^\r\n"]*)*\K\R+`](https://regex101.com/r/pL1vA2/2).

Answer (score 1):

The regex to remove all linebreaks inside a non-nested `p` tag, is

```
(<p>|(?!^)\G)(?:(?!</?p>)[^\r\n])*\K\R+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF9nP6/1).

In short,

- `(<p>|(?!^)\G)` - Group 1 matching a `<p>` or the end of the previous successful match
- `(?:(?!</?p>)[^\r\n])*` - matches 0+ sequences of any char other than a LF/CR that does not start a `</p>` or `<p>` sequence
- `\K` - omits the matched text
- `\R+` - what we only match is this, 1+ newline sequences (CRLFs, CRs or LFs).

**NOTE** that unrolling the pattern as

```
(<p>|\G(?!^))[^\r\n<]*(?:<(?!/?p>)[^\r\n<]*)*\K\R+
```

will boost the S&R performance ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/mF9nP6/2)).

[image]

**VVVVVVV**

[image]